# Acentos en base de datos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Esto es lo que pasó, tenía información en una hoja de Excel, la convertí a CSV y la importé a una base de datos por medio de phpMyAdmin, el detalle es que en dicha información en algunos registros tiene ñ y acentos. Logré importarlos declarando

> Character set of the file: iso-8859-1

Y pues nada, logré mostrar acentos al momento de consultar en phpMyAdmin, pero cuando intento consultarlos en una página web las ñ y acentos se convierten a �.

También noté que cuando se hace una alta por medio de php estos en phpMyAdmin aparecen de una manera en particular, aparecen así:

```
Ã±
Ã¡
Ã©
Ã
Ã³
Ãº
```

Sin embargo, estos últimos al consultarlos en las páginas web sí que se muestran como deben de ser, con ñ y acentos.

```
ñ = Ã±
á = Ã¡
é = Ã©
í = Ã
ó = Ã³
ú = Ãº
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Qué puedo hacer para que consulte con acentos (no los caracteres 
raros)?

O tal vez, ¿Me conviene dejarlo con los caracteres raros? Si es así pues tendría que buscar una manera de cambiar los acentos y ñ en la base de datos y reemplazarlos con dichos caracteres raros, esto para que los registros antiguos se puedan consultar sin que aparezca el �.

Si es necesario que ponga parte de mi código lo haré cuanto antes.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base). El problema es explicado con amplitud en la respuesta a esa pregunta. Recomendaría que, en vez de `iso-8859-1`, establezcas la codificación a **`utf-8` en todas partes**, será la mejor garantía de que todo irá bien.

Comment: Lo hacía con esa codificación y todas las ñ y acentos se convertían a "?".

Comment: Raúl, si estableces todo a `utf-8` uniformemente no tendrás problemas en la codificación, está comprobado, pero como explico en la respuesta enlazada más arriba, debes aplicar esa codificación en todos los niveles, es la única forma de resolver el problema de raíz.

Comment: Ya está, revisé el enlace y la respuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo resolviste aplicando esos criterios Raúl?

Comment: Sí, mi problema también estuvo en el nivel 3, no tenía idea de eso de establecer la codificación.